# Converting componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.active !== nextProps.active) {
      Animated.timing(this._active, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.bounce,
        toValue: Number(nextProps.active),
      }).start();
    }
  }
```

This is the code of react-native-sortable-list.
And what I am trying to do is change this code with react-hook

Is there any help can I get to change  componentWillReceiveProps part to functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` with dependency list. when `props.active` changes component will rerender

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Animated.timing(props.active, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.bounce,
        toValue: Number(props.active),
      }).start();
},[props.active])
```